# Facebook Graph API の /user/home で得られる投稿と実際のホームの投稿が違っている

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

FacebookのGraph APIで/{user-id}/homeを使って投稿を取得すると、Facebook本家のサイトのホームに表示される投稿とずいぶん違いませんか？

投稿されてから取得できるまでタイムラグがあるとか、多少違うのはいいんです。
でも結構前に投稿された物なのに全く取得できないとかで詰みませんか？

Facebookグループに突撃しても英語が酷かったらしくてスルーされてたし、誰か代わりに英訳してくれませんか？
もしくは解決方法をご存知の方がいましたら教えて下さい。

友達の一覧から一人ずつ投稿を取得するのとかエレガントじゃないですよね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

リファレンスを見る限りニュースフィードの取得は生のデータ（read_stream）が流れてくるみたいですね。
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/home
それに対してウェブの画面に表示されるデータは「ハイライト」「最新情報」「未読のもの」などの条件付けに加え、ユーザビヘイビアに基づいてかなりフィルタされたものが配信されています。
これに似たような挙動をさせるには FQL stream_filter table を使いなさいと書いてあります。