# facebookのAPIでFQLでしか取れない情報はFQLが廃止された後どうやって取得するのか？

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

趣味で一人で開発をしているため情報が入ってこず、不思議に思っているのですが、
facebookのFQLが廃止された後、graph APIで代用出来ない情報はどうすればいいのかご存知の方はいますでしょうか？

例えば複数枚の画像が貼られている投稿から全ての画像を取り出したいとき、postidを使ってFQLで

```
SELECT post_id,attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id="12345"
```

としてattachmentの中を見ないと情報が取得出来なかったり、
(graphAPIだと1枚しかとれない)

[Facebook Graph API の /user/home で得られる投稿と実際のホームの投稿が違っている](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/374/facebook-graph-api-%E3%81%AE-user-home-%E3%81%A7%E5%BE%97%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%A8%E5%AE%9F%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AE%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%8C%E9%81%95%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B)

ここの頂いた回答にもあるんですが、
graphAPIのuser/homeでは取得できず、stream_filterを使った方がいいとか、
そういうものがあると思います。

「〇〇は廃止するから××を使いなさい」みたいなアナウンスも公式で見かけたりするんですが、上記のようなものについて何かしらのアナウンスを見かけた事はありません。

みなさんにお伺いしたいのは、

・上記のリクエストを含むFQLの代替について公式からアナウンスが出ているのでしょうか？

ということです。

出ていたら私の調べ方が甘かったとか、出ていなかったら公式に突撃しなきゃいけない、とかあるかもしれませんが、
まずは、一人で開発している私に、今どういうステータスになっているのかについてご教授頂けたらと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

開発者向けのブログをチェックするとリリースノートは見れると思います。ただ、個人でやっているだけだとそこまでチェックするのは難しいですね。

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/

v2.2のアナウンスはこれのようですが、あまり細かいことは書いてありませんね。

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/10/30/graph-api-v2.2/

詳細なチェンジログはこちら。

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2

あ、FQL使わなくても取れるようになるって書いてありますね？

> /v2.1/{post-id} will now return all photos attached to the post: In
>   previous versions of the API only the first photo was returned with a
>   post. This removes the need to use FQL to get all a post's photos.

またバグレポートを検索すると、同じような状況で質問をしている人がいたりするので業務でFBアプリを開発する際は日常的にチェックしていました。

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/trending/

そもそもFQL自体は使うなという方向だと思いますのでGraph API中心に移して、ダメな部分は個別にバグレポートするのがよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: おーありがとうございます！
複数枚の画像の件は私のチェック漏れで、バグレポートについてはノーチェックだったので見てみます。
ぼんやりした質問に対して答えを頂けるのはありがたいですね。